# specific profile cannot change field (validation rule)

Tags: validation-rule

I want to create a rule where the User with the "Call center" profile will only be able to fill in the "Name" field just by creating the Customer record. Once the record is created, it will not be able to update the "Name" field
Valid for the various record types

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You should [edit] your question to tell us what you have tried and point to a very specific thing that you're stuck on. If you're getting any error messages, you should include the full, unmodified text of the error.

Comment: When you work on this I recommend use of a [custom permission](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/custom_perms_overview.htm) rather than taking the usual bad-practice approach of testing profile names.